# Aggregate and flatten an array field in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema:

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    topics: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Topic'
    }],
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

What I want to do is get an array with all topics from all projects. I cannot query Topic directly and get a full list because some topics are unassigned and they do not hold a reference back to a Project (for reasons of avoiding two way references). So I need to query Project and aggregate some how. I am doing something like:

```
Project.aggregate([{$project:{topics:1}}]);
```

But this is giving me an array of Project objects with the topics field. What I want is an array with topic objects.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please post the sample output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When dealing with arrays you typically want to use [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the array members first and then [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to find the distinct entries:

```js
Project.aggregate(
    [
        { "$unwind": "$topics" },
        { "$group": { "_id": "$topics._id" } }
    ],
    function(err,docs) {

    }
)
```

But for this case, it is probably simplier to just use [`.distinct()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.distinct) which will do the same as above, but with just an array of results rather than documents:

```js
Project.distinct("topics._id",function(err,topics) {

});
```

But wait there a minute because I know what you are **really** asking here. It's not the `_id` values you want but your `Topic` data has a property on it like "name".

Since your items are "referenced" and in another collection, you cannot do an aggregation pipeline or `.distinct()` operation on the property of a document in another collection. Put basically "MongoDB does not perform Joins" and mongoose `.populate()` is **not** a join, just something that "emulates" that with additional query(ies).

But you can of course just find the "distinct" values from "Project" and then fetch the information from "Topic". As in:

```js
Project.distinct("topics._id",function(err,topics) {
    Topic.find({ "_id": { "$in": topics } },function(err,topics) {

    });
});
```

Which is handy because the `.distinct()` function already returned an array suitable for use with [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It almost worked as long as I wrote Project.distinct("topics", function(err, topicIDs) {});

Comment: @MikeM My bad, as I generally have "embedding" on the brain or did when writing. With a referenced array of course the value is just the `ObjectId` value in the array with no sub-properties as you have noted.